# Place holder for `Textarea` not working in `Bootstrap`

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message
       </label>
       <div class="col-lg-10">
           <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message">
           </textarea> 
       </div><!--end col 10-->
     </div><!--ends from group-->
```

I am new to `Bootstrap`. I was trying to use `placeholder` in `textarea`.I was not able to see the `Placeholer`values in my `textarea`.Please help me in this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Placeholder text is only shown when there is no content in the input component.

The `<textarea>` element you have is not empty - there is whitespace between the start and ending tags.

The fix is to remove this whitespace:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message
   </label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
       <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
   </div><!--end col 10-->
 </div><!--ends from group-->
```

Answer (score 5):

The opening and closing tags for the `<textarea>` element must be on the same line, otherwise a newline character occupies it. 
The placeholder will therefore not be displayed since the input area contains content which is a `newline`.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message
   </label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
       <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea> 
   </div><!--end col 10-->
 </div><!--ends from group-->
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zejffuen/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message
       </label>
       <div class="col-lg-10">    
<textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" cols="20"  rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
 </div><!--end col 10-->
     </div><!--ends from group-->
```